# ionic3 form fire the function twice when submit

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

i am using form submit below:

```
  <form [formGroup]="forgetpwdForm" (submit)="doForgetPwdRequest()">
     <ion-item style="border:1px solid #CCCCCC; border-radius:0px;">
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="forgetpwdData.email" name="email" type="text" formControlName="email" placeholder="{{ 'Forgetpassword.email' | translate }}"></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
     <button ion-button block style="border-radius:0px; background-color:#17B97E;" type="submit" [disabled]="!forgetpwdForm.valid">
      {{ 'Forgetpassword.submit' | translate }}
     </button>      
  </form>
```

And I discover that it fired doForgetPwdRequest() twice when submit the form, anyone have idea?

app.module.ts bootstraps:

```
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
  MyApp,
  LandPage,
  forgetpwdPage
],
```

Comment: Can you show the `ts` file's code also?

Answer (score 0):

In your `main.ts` you have to set:

```
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms()]);
```

See this link for reference. [ngSubmit fires twice when submit button clicked](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9954)

Comment: hi, you means app.module.ts? how to set the bootstrap? above i have place the bootstrap part at app.module.ts, sorry I am new at this.

Comment: No, in your project there is one file called `main.ts`.

Comment: ic, thanks, but after i put it in and have error below:
Module '"/Users/nulra/Downloads/test/node_modules/@angular/forms/forms"' has no exported member 'disableDeprecatedForms'.